# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class <..> to Class <...>

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I've 'inherited' an Eclipse RCP project which seems to work fine with a target platform set based around 3.6.  However, moving forward we need to update to the latest version of the platform, but when I change the target platform to 3.7 (or 4.2) I get a handful of errors along the lines of

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#1-of ?> to Class<? extends IDatasetProvider>
```

Can anyone suggest/provide an explanation of why this might work fine in 3.6, but not in 3.7 (and later)? Any ideas as to where I would start in resolving this would also be great!

A snippet of the code causing this error (which appears at the b.loadClass part):

```
    List<Class<? extends IDatasetProvider>> list = new LinkedList<Class<? extends IDatasetProvider>>();
    ClassMap<IDatasetProvider, List<String>> map = new ClassMap<IDatasetProvider, List<String>>();

    for (IConfigurationElement e : elements)
    {
        try
        {
            Bundle b = Platform.getBundle(e.getContributor().getName());

            String viewId = e.getAttribute("viewId");
            Class<? extends IDatasetProvider> datasetType = b.loadClass(e
                    .getAttribute("datasetProvider"));
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }
     }
```

There are also 3 (possibly) related warnings

```
 IDatasetProvider is a raw type. References to generic type IDatasetProvider<T> should be parameterized
```

If I change back to our 3.6 platform, it all works again.

EDIT: fixed thanks to the help of Alexy and gzukmin.

I used the following code, specifically casting to `Class<? extends IDatasetProvider>` rather than just `Class`:

```
Class<? extends IDatasetProvider> datasetType = 
    (Class<? extends IDatasetProvider>) b.loadClass(e.getAttribute("datasetProvider"));
```

If there's any reason I should consider just casting to the more generic `Class`, please let me know!

Comment: I assume that it will be userful to see `loadClass` method signature.

Comment: Do you mean the:  `Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException;` line from the org.osgi.framework.Bundle class?

Comment: Are you using the same version of Java under 3.6, 3.7, and 4.2?

Comment: Exactly. So, you try to assign a `Class<?>` object to the `Class<? extends IDatasetProvider>` variable, which produce error (I suppose). This is because `Class<?>` is not subtype of `Class<? extends IDatasetProvider>`.  May be in previous version `Class<?>` was a rawtype `Class` and instead of error compiler produced warnings that were ignored.

Comment: It's JDK 1.6 / JRE6 for all versions of eclipse.

Comment: You were correct gkuzmin.  Just to confirm, in the 3.6 version/target, `loadClass` did simply return a rawtype `Class`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just cast it to raw type like this:

```
Class<? extends IDatasetProvider> datasetType = 
    (Class) b.loadClass(e.getAttribute("datasetProvider"));
```

Note this will:

1. Add more warnings about raw types and unchecked casts.
2. Blow up at the runtime if your class actually turns out not to extend `IDatasetProvider`. And not at the cast location, but later when you try to actually use the class. So it might be a good idea to check this with

   ```
   IDatasetProvider.class.isAssignableFrom(datasetType)
   ```

(see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)).

Comment: Joshua Bloch in Efficient Java book wrote that raw types are deprecated attribute from legacy code, which should be avoided. I think that It is better to use cast to particular type `Class<? extends IDatasetProvider>` and turn off unchecked cast warning with `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")`. It will have the same effect as code that you proposed, but without raw type `Class` and warning from compiler. And how do you intend to check if class actually extends `IDatasetProvider`?

Comment: @gkuzmin Yes, you can use `@SuppressWarning` in both cases. You still have warning about raw type `IDatasetProvider` if you cast to `Class<? extends IDatasetProvider>`. If casting to `Class<? extends IDatasetProvider<?>>` compiles, it would really be better. See edited answer for the last question.

Comment: This solution is very nice! I totally forgot about `isAssignableFrom` method. I think that this method is very useful if class is not generic.

Comment: Thanks for answer/guidance, which I've finally implemented.  The question has been edited to include the solution I used...

Comment: and not wanting to be pedantic, but I've just noticed it should be `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` and not @SuppressWarning("unchecked")

Comment: @jonny Rather than cast to the raw type `Class` it would be better to use `b.loadClass(e.getAttribute("datasetProvider")).asSubclass(IDatasetProvider.class)`, which will (a) not require an explicit cast, (b) not generate any warnings and (c) fail-fast with a `ClassCastException` if the loaded class is not an implementation of `IDatasetProvider`.