# Java Generics: what does <? extends Interface <?>> mean?

Tags: java, generics

Further to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363788/type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-class-to-class) I'm hope someone can help clarify/confirm my understanding of the following java generics statements, and offer some input as to what the final one means:

If:

```
Class<abc> className = x
```

means to assign `x` of type `abc` to  `Class` variable `className`

And:

```
Class<? extends IAbc> className = x
```

means to assigns `x` which implements interface `IAbc` to `Class` variable `className`

What does:

```
Class<? extends IAbc<?>> className = x
```

mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That just means that `IAbc` is itself a generic type `IAbc<T>`, you're asking for a `Class` object representing some implementation of some parameterization of `IAbc` but you don't know (or care?) which.

More interesting would be something like

```
Class<? extends IAbc<? extends Number>>
```

which would accept any class that implements `IAbc<Number>`, `IAbc<Integer>`, `IAbc<Double>`, etc.